# Matlab indexing error

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

SO I have this DSP code:

```
    frameLength = 256;
fileReader = dsp.AudioFileReader(...
    'sound.mp3',...
    'SamplesPerFrame',frameLength);
deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter(...
    'SampleRate',fileReader.SampleRate);
scope = dsp.TimeScope(...
    'SampleRate',fileReader.SampleRate,...
    'TimeSpan',16,...
    'BufferLength',1.5e6,...
    'YLimits',[-1 1]);
dRG = noiseGate(...
    'SampleRate',fileReader.SampleRate,...
    'Threshold',-25,...
    'AttackTime',10e-3,...
    'ReleaseTime',20e-3,...
    'HoldTime',0);

visualize(dRG);

configureMIDI(dRG);

while ~isDone(fileReader)
    signal = fileReader();
    noisySignal = signal + 0.0025*randn(frameLength,1);
    processedSignal = dRG(noisySignal);
    deviceWriter(processedSignal);
    scope([noisySignal,processedSignal]);

end

release(fileReader);
release(deviceWriter);
release(scope);
release(dRG);
```

And it gives me this error, I tried to index it in every way, with cells too, but it doesn't seem to work. The error is:

> Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class 'dsp.AudioFileReader' is not allowed.  Use objects
>   of class 'dsp.AudioFileReader' only as scalars or use a cell array.
>
> Error in workbench (line 25)
>       signal = fileReader();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the incorrect usage of `dsp.AudioFileReader`.

You first did:

> ```
> fileReader = dsp.AudioFileReader(...
>     'sound.mp3',...
>     'SamplesPerFrame',frameLength);
> ```

Then later :

> ```
> signal = fileReader();
> ```

I think this last line is the problem... your usage of the dsp.AudioFileReader System object is not correct. Like the error message says, the usage of parentheses after `fileReader` doesn't make sense.

Depending on what you want to do, you should call the correct method (list of correct methods [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.audiofilereader-system-object.html)).

For example, if you want to use the method  `step`, you should do:

> ```
> signal = step(fileReader);
> ```